# Git Remove Added Commits with Large Files

Tags: git, github, version-control

I accidentally added some large files into my git commit. After this I have deleted the large files and now I want to commit the remaining changes (excluding the large files) but somehow the deletion of the large files are still in my git history and therefore I cannot make any further commits. I do not want to git reset HARD or something and lose a lot of my local changes. How do I resolve this?

My steps:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Commiting with Large Files"
git push origin main
-- Failed to push due to Large files
```

Now I delete these large files from my local machine and try to push again

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Commiting with deleted large files"
git push origin main
-- Failed to push
```

I tried

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git reset
```

but I still have the deleted files as unstaged changes which is preventing from a new git add -A and push.

```
Unstaged changes after reset:
D   largefile/b_qty.tar.gz
D   largefile/b_qty.txt
D   largefile/s_qty.tar.gz
D   largefile/s_qty.txt
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? I really cannot lose any of my local changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use
`git restore --staged .`

To unstage files or to unstage a specific file use

`git restore --staged <individual_file>`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you have the following commits:

```
def - Commiting with deleted large files
abc - Commiting with Large Files
```

so when you undo the commit `def`, it is normal that git still sees these files as deleted: you still have commit `abc` where you added those files.

If you want to get a nice view of your commit graph, try:

```
git log --all --graph --oneline --decorate
```

This will help you diagnose. Probably you should rewrite both of your commits, so

```
git reset HEAD~2
```

might do the trick, but again: analyze your git graph to see what you need to do, which commits to reset,...